# How to zoom jqplot from external button?

Tags: zooming, jqplot

I am using jqplot chart to draw chart it works fine, To zoom chart i am using cursor and by that cursor i can zoom but i am trying to zoom that from button that is outside of chart. Since we are reset the zoomed chart from external button like this `$('#reset').click(function() {plot1.resetZoom() });` so is it possible to do zoom chart from external button. Please advice...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this isn't a complete answer as I see no desire for me to ever want this, but you have two options as I see it:

1. You could determine your "zoom factor" which you would apply to min(x,y), max(x,y) then `replot()` with the new options.  The drawback to this is that you could not zoom out with a double-click.  You could invoke a `replot()` using default zoom factor on a custom plot double-click handler.
2. You could find out what handlers are involved in clicking and dragging on the plot and simulate that with a fixed co-ordinates -- basically the "zoom factor" again

Comment: Do you have any example for this?
Since you were wondering of a use case for this, it could be a good workaround to enable zooming on a touchscreen device, since the cursor  plgin can not really be tracked on a touch device. only the click and doubleclick events work on a touch device.

Answer (score -2):

Hi Swan i think you need to use this function [Enable plot Zooming](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-cursor-js.html#%24.jqplot.Cursor.zoom)
hope it will helpful for you. All the best

Again jqPlot is an awesome javascript graphing library, supporting loads of cool features. Except clickable bar charts.
Here is a plugin which allows you to capture click events for bar charts.

```
$.jqplot('Graph', data, {
barClickable: {
    onClick: function(i, j, data){
alert("Clicked series: " + i + ", data point: " + j + ", data: " + data);
    }
}});
```

Comment: you are correct we can enable it by zoom = false but it zooms inside chart but i want to zoom it from outside button... check my question.